# Java: Load a chinese ResourceBundle (Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese) not working

Tags: java, localization, resourcebundle, chinese-locale

In my Java application I create a `Locale` like this:

```
new Locale("es") // for spanish
new Locale (Locale.ITALIAN)
new Locale ("gu") // for Gujarati
```

Now the correct ResourceBundle- textfile will be loaded by doing this:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale, loader);
```

The resource textfiles are located in a separate folder with names:

```
MessagesBundle_es.txt, MessagesBundle_it.txt, MessagesBundle_ru.txt, etc...
```

They are all loaded well (russian (-->cyrillic), Turkish, Czech, German, Spanish, Italian, etc...)

But there is a problem with Chinese. 
In the code for traditional and simplified Chinese, I create the `Locale`- Object like these versions:

```
locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE; //or
locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE; //or
locale= new Locale ("zh","cn") //or
locale= new Locale ("zh","tw") //or
locale= new Locale ("zh","CN") //or
locale= new Locale ("zh","TW") //or
```

If the MessagesBundle - file is called:

```
MessagesBundle_zh.txt
```

the Bundle will be loaded.
But if the Bundle is called

```
MessagesBundle_zh_CN or MessagesBundle_zh_TW //other postfixes: _zh-TX, _zh_Hans, etc..
```

to differentiate between simplified and traditional Chinese, the ResourceBundle is ignored and the default Bundle:

```
MessagesBundle.txt
```

(English in this case) is loaded

I tried several Versions of postfixes of the MessagesBundle Files, and many versions to create the Locales, but, alas, with no success. 
What can I try next. I have read a lot of similar Questions, but none worked for me.

Comment: I tried the following: Locale.CHINA and Locale.Taiwan VS. Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE and Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE. All versions will result in the following output: getLanguage=zh;
getCountry= ;
getDisplayCountry= ;
getVariant= ;
getDisplayLanguage=中文;
getDisplayName=中文;
getDisplayScript= ;
currentLocale.getDisplayLanguage()=中文;

Comment: So I have no chance to distinguish simplified vs traditional Chinese?

Comment: ...and always the MessagesBundle_zh.txt  only will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your buddle don't support such names like "MessagesBundle_zh_CN.txt".  In fact, you can just use zh.txt, cause zh-cn/zh-tw could be read by both sides with no much difficult